# PHP HMVC and module Headers

Tags: php, hmvc, response-headers

If a user requests a web page which is handled by a PHP controller under an HMVC framework, and that controller subsequently calls a 'module' controller and saves the output to a variable, will any 'headers' output by the 'module' be returned to the users browser?

I'm wondering if a modules headers might/could be prematurely processed by the users browser as being "the response" when the actual response from the main controller is still coming.

Comment: What happened when you tested this?  You may want to include that in the question and make a significant attempt to research/test it.

Comment: This depends on the framework in question. It is certainly the case that outputting content will prevent new headers being sent, so the framework/modules/controllers need to collaborate to ensure everything gets sent in the right order.